# Remove WhiteSpace from Int type Array in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

Please review my array below and see space in string.I don't why string get space.

```
var workFlowID = [Int]()

let metaData = realm.objects(MetaData.self)
        print(metaData)
        for item in metaData {
            let workdflow = item["workflow"] as! Int
            workFlowID.append(workdflow)
        }

 workFlowID = [39, 39, 39, 39, 39]
 let uniqueArray = Array(Set(workFlowID))
 uniqueArray = [39]

 var shaString = String()
 shaString = String(format:"{\"workflow\":%d}",uniqueArray)
```

**Output shaString is** "{\"workflow\":(\n    39\n)}"

Comment: "uniqueArray: Int = [39]" doesn't cause issue? Because it should. And I think that you want to use JSONSerialization. Or at least do `String(format:"{\"workflow\":%d}",uniqueArray.first)` if it's really an array. Put real code. How did you get `uniqueArray`?

Comment: @Larme please check edit question

Comment: @Larme i am fetched data from realm database

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The code wouldn't work. 
If you are looking to print the uniqueArray then here is the modification.

`uniqueArray: [Int] = [39]
var shaString = String()
shaString = String(format:"{\"workflow\":\(uniqueArray)}")`

Answer (score 0):

if `uniqueArray` is an array means it should be a `[Int]` not `Int`.

```
uniqueArray: [Int] = [39]
var shaString = String()
shaString = String(format:"{\"workflow\":%d}",uniqueArray)
```

and above line only give `{"workflow":2296608}`

if that in `Int` means you need to use

```
uniqueArray: Int = 39
var shaString = String()
shaString = String(format:"{\"workflow\":%d}",uniqueArray)
```

and  that will give  `{"workflow":39}`